# Sending mail with attachment from Python using SMTP

Tags: python, email, smtp, attachment

I HAVE A LITTLE PROBLEM.

I USE:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'me@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'you@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email in python'
message = 'here is the email'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
# identify ourselves to smtp gmail client
mailserver.ehlo()
# secure our email with tls encryption
mailserver.starttls()
# re-identify ourselves as an encrypted connection
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('me@gmail.com', 'mypassword')

mailserver.sendmail('me@gmail.com','you@gmail.com',msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()
```

AND EVERTHING IS OKAY - BUT I WOULD LIKE TO ADD A TXT FILE ATTACHMENT. CAN YOU HELP ME?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T USE ALL CAPS. IT'S LIKE SHOUTING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve it like this:

```
filename = ...
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    message = MIMEText(f.read())
    message.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    msg.attach(message)
```

where `msg` is the `MIMEMultiPart` object.

Answer (score 0):

I FIND ANSWER TO BUT THANKS A LOT ! :)

```
 filename='/www/pages/DANE/komunikaty.txt'
    fp=open(filename,'rb')
    att = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fp.read(),_subtype="txt")
    fp.close()
    att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)
    msg.attach(att)
```